Switching from a mainly Shimano Alivio 3 x 9 configuration to a mainly Shimano 3 x 10 configuration
Greetings to everyone and all from a newcomer to this forum. I have in mind the following hypothetical scenario:

a happy bike owner has a hardtail equipped with a Shimano Alivio 3x9 configuration (to be more explicit, the hardtail in question is actually the Mongoose Tyax Comp of 2014; this part of the scenario is quite real and not just hypothetical)
assume the owner of the respective hardtail were thinking of making the transition from his current 3x9 Alivio setup to a Shimano 3x10 configuration
the main concern of the owner is that apparently many of the components required for a 3x10 build seem to be discontinued from production (thus no longer available on the market), most likely due to the recent tendency of MTB producers to implement at most 2 gear chainrings in their drivetrain design.

What advice could be given to the above owner, in order to help him succeed in procuring all the necessary components needed for a smooth-running 3x10 configuration? (the title mentions a Shimano-centered build, however this requirement can be relaxed to accommodate any other high-quality producers).
With anticipated gratitude, looking forward to the ideas and counsel of the more experienced members of this forum!

What components does the owner of the bike wants to keep? (note that the 3xX has survived in Shimano in the "trekking" range, that has only been recently discontinued so finding components should still be doable). Replacing wear parts is generally cheap - or doing minor upgrades, but I were to replace the whole drivetrain, I'd switch to 2x or 1x (from the CUES range).

@Renaud Thank you for the answer! The owner currently has an Alivio M311 chainring, meant for 8/9 speed cassettes, so under the hypothesis of introducing a 10 speed cassette this chainring should be replaced with a compatible one..if the chainring is to be replaced, theoretically so should the derailleurs and clearly the rear shifter (to accommodate for the intended 10 s cassette). To conclude, the most that could be preserved from the current setup is the front shifter. All in all, if the owner is to succeed with his fancy of introducing 3x10 it's safe to say everything should be replaced..

Shimano has deprecated almost everything that is triple.   The used market is a fair source of parts but pricing is all over.

Don't bother? 10sp doesn't win you much over 9sp, and 9sp parts are easily available and in similar and better quality to what is currently on the bike

I'd skip 3x10 and move to 1x12. You are still going to need to change a lot, so why stopping there?

If the owner is happy with a 3x9 Alivio from 2014, the most sensible/economical decision is to replace the worn components by equivalent ones (cables are included in the components and are often overlooked as a cause of poor shifting). Alivio/Acera didn't evolve significantly in the meantime, so replacing components only to have new ones won't make a significant difference (unless they are worn of course).
If for some reason, the whole drivetrain needs to be replaced, 3x10 is not where I would go to, as it's a dead-end and not a significant upgrade over an Alivio (more crisp shifting, one additional speed but the range remains equivalent, so no functional gain). If you find a groupset in second hand in good condition, why not, but new, the price is generally in the same order of magnitude than any other groupset of similar level.
So on this basis, I'd rather take a more modern/recent groupset. I'm thinking to CUES more specifically, that finally offers a range comparable to 3x but on a 2x (46-32 front, 11-45 rear) in the U6020 range (equivalent to Deore) or U8020 range (equivalent to XT) - it was possible before, but with hacks. To have the two (a 3x9 with LX components from the late 2000's and a 2x10 comparable to U6020, but prior to it so hack-based), I find the 2x much better, mostly because the wide-range cassette allows to switch chainrings less often, clutched derailleurs offer better chain retention on rougher terrain and 2x front derailleurs can now be operated with single lever shifters (pushed forward for the big ring, backwards for the small ring, so you can know on which ring you are by checking the lever, without having to look at the rings/an indicator). But these are refinements that are not worth a full upgrade IMHO, so the 3x9 bike remains in 3x9 as long as the groupset remains functional. If I would need to replace the groupset, I would however consider a 2x or 1x, depending on the priorities of the moment (2x would be for range, 1x for ease of operation/maintenance).

@Renaud Thank you once again for the very detailed answer!
